# Error:CreateProcess error=216and also IDE fatal error

Tags: java, android-studio, windows-7, ide

[createprocess=216 and also the IDE fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX3wi.jpg)

Comment: what are you doing when this occurs?

Comment: just i  closed the IDE window but it eventually comes every time when i launched the application

Comment: The message on the bottom says your version of Windows is not compatible.

Comment: but i have downloaded the x86(32bit) version java and android studio 2.3.3 then what i need to update??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your directory where the JDK is located, by default Studio uses embedded JDK but for some reason it produces error=216.

Comment: Did you installed 32 bit studio?